# How to link to specific tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to link to specific tabs using flickity.css http://flickity.metafizzy.co/ and i'm having trouble. I know this has been a common problem using php but is there a known method (possibly using javascript) to create unique urls for all of the tabs created inside of "nav nav-tabs"? I'm trying to use a redirect to link to a certain tab after an event is completed. Using php would there be a way to path to that specific event?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id = "tab-style">
     <li class = "active"><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#profile"></li>
     <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#friends"></a></li> 
     <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#games"></a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#context"></a></li> 
</ul>
```

That is the code for creating the tabs all inside the same html file. The divs are created in the standard way. For example.

```
<div id = "profile" class "tab-pane fade in active">
     tab contents
</div>
<div id="friends" class="tab-pane fade">
</div>
```

and so on...

Comment: Could you please explain what you wanted to do actually? This is very little information you provided.

Comment: I want each tab in the nav nav-tabs to have a unique url so i can link to each of them directly. @AKA

Comment: you mean to say when you access that link in browser you can directly view that tab open in browser?

Comment: @AKA correct i want to be able to access the specific link in my browser that would open that tab directly. Right now I can only link to my active tab

Comment: i can see your offer in upwork. Can you please send me that and i will do it through it.